# Why does this integral hold / What is test density?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I just start reading the book "distributions theory and applications" in order to understand the notion of generalized function and densities

The following statement is from that book:

"In undergraduate physics a lecturer will be tempted to say on certain occasions:  Let $\delta(x)$ be a function define on the line that equals 0 away from 0 and is infinite at 0 in such a way that it's total integral is 1. the most important property of $\delta(x)$ is exemplified by the identity

$\int\limits_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \phi(x)\delta(x)dx= \phi(0) \qquad ... (*)$,

Where $\phi$ is a continuous function of x ".

1. Why is the equation (*) true ?
2. Could you please explain  or point me to a reference wich explain the notion of "test density" in a context other then  the probability theory, I've search for it but all find is the notion of test function and the notion density in probability!

Thanks!

Comment: The statement "Let $\delta(x)$ be a function define on the line that equals $0$ away from $0$ and is infinite at $0$ in such a way that it's total integral is $1$," .is totally non-sensical.  There is no function that "is infinite" at a point.  Moreover, the integral of a function that is equal to $0$ almost everywhere is $0$.  However, there is something called a generalized function, or distribution, called the Dirac Delta $\delta$, that has the property that for every test function $\phi \in C_C^\infty$, the linear functional $\langle \delta, \phi \rangle=\phi(0)$.

Comment: Thank your comment! I understand your point! I will add in my question  the statement in the book before that one, which for sure will clear up ambiguities .

Comment: @MarkViola, of course, the almost-everywhere-0 objection is most persuasive in a situation where we implicitly believe that measure theory is the umbrella context. And, then, as you say, something fails. But, more and more, I've come to think that iconic argument proves that measure theory is inadequate, rather than "there's no $\delta$", since the conflict is that measure theory is a too limited idea...

Comment: Not called test density but certainly fits the idea here is the notion of "test classes" which consist of so-called "test functions" in the area of variational calculus which in some sense this is. In general, you can find a lot of information on distribution theory in advanced functional analysis books. Note that you might dig deeper into the notions of Dual and reflexive spaces to fully grasp distribution theory.

Comment: Note that the author writes "In undergraduate physics a lecturer will be tempted to say on certain occasions". With this he tells the reader that it is common among physicists to explain the delta function in the following way, but that it is not mathematically stringent. To a physics student that explanation is enough and going into mathematical rigor would take too much time and lead focus away from the current topic.